# El problema de woocommerce y los recargos de equivalencia en españa

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Supongamos que tengamos una Tienda en Woocommerce, donde a los los productos se le aplican el 10%
es decir, IVA Reducido, pero al envio que es tipo Flat, se le aplica el 21%.

En los Tax rate tengo la siguiente configuracion:

**IVA 10**

```
* * * * "10.000" "PRODUCTO IVA 10%"  1 false false
```

**IVA 10 RE**

```
* * * * "10.000" "PRODUCTO IVA 10%"  1 false false
* * * * "1.4000" "PRODUCTO RE  1.4%" 2 false false
```

**ENVÍO 21**

```
* * * * "21.000" "ENVÍO IVA 21%"     1 false true
```

**ENVÍO 21 RE**

```
* * * * "21.000" "ENVÍO IVA 21%"     1 false true
* * * * "5.4000" "ENVÍO RE  5.4%"    2 false true
```

**Nota:** la Tienda puede vender solo para ESPAÑA!

En las Opciones de Impuesto, tengo lo siguiente:

[image: Imagen 1]

Y he clonado el rol de "Customer", le he llamado "CON RE", para luego con el plugin de "*User Role editor*" asignar la opción de Recargo de Equivalencia a algunos clientes.

Usando la siguiente función, puedo determinar que los usuarios con el role "CON RE", se le aplique el "tax class" con o sin RE.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_tax_product_func', 25, 1 );
function set_tax_product_func( $cart ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && in_array( 'con-re', $user_data->roles ) ) {
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class("IVA 10 RE");
        }
    } else {
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class("IVA 10");
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEMA:**

El "SHIPPING tax class" que se configura en las opciones de impuestos en woocommerce, la cual se almacena en la tabla de opciones, determina la clase de impuesto a los envios y que una solución rápida en esta situación sería añadir una linea antes del If. Ej:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_tax_product_func', 25, 1 );
function set_tax_product_func( $cart ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && in_array( 'con-re', $user_data->roles ) ) {
        update_option('woocommerce_shipping_tax_class', 'iva-21-re', true); //<--------
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class("IVA 10 RE");
        }
    } else {
        update_option('woocommerce_shipping_tax_class', 'iva-21', true); //<----------
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class("IVA 10");
        }
    }
}
```

Pero creo que no seria eficiente esto, Lo ideal seria, que la opción de *woocommerce_shipping_tax_class* no fuera global, debido a que si realizan 2 o mas clientes un pedido (por ejemplo un cliente con RE y otro sin RE), sospecho que podría dar conflicto ¿correcto?

No existe (hasta donde se por largas horas de investigación) un filtro que pueda utilizar para hacer un set en *woocommerce_shipping_tax_class*, algo parecido al código anterior.

**OTRO ESCENARIO:**

En vez de trabajar con 4 Tax Classes. intente crear 2 nada mas teniendo lo siguiente:

**IVA SIN RE**

```
* * * * "10.000" "PRODUCTO IVA 10%"  1 false false
* * * * "21.000" "ENVÍO IVA 21%"     2 false true
```

**IVA CON RE**

```
* * * * "10.000" "PRODUCTO IVA 10%"  1 false false
* * * * "1.4000" "PRODUCTO RE  1.4%" 2 false false
* * * * "21.000" "ENVÍO IVA 21%"     3 false true
* * * * "5.4000" "ENVÍO RE  5.4%"    4 false true
```

Aplicando la siguiente función similar:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_tax_product_func', 25, 1 );
function set_tax_product_func( $cart ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_data = get_userdata($user_id);
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && in_array( 'con-re', $user_data->roles ) ) {
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class("IVA CON RE");
        }
    } else {
        foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class("IVA SIN RE");
        }
    }
}
```

**PROBLEMA:**

Casi seria la solución pero ME ACUMULA EL PRECIO DEL PRODUCTO Y EL ENVÍO y son de impuestos distintos lo cual no es viable.

[image: Imagen 2]

Answer (score 0):

Use el plugin recargo de equivalencia y agregue este codigo a function.php

```
function yourname_fix_shipping_tax( $taxes, $price, $rates) {
    foreach ( get_option('woocommerce_re_roles', array()) as $role ) {
        if ( current_user_can( $role ) ) {  
            $taxes_re = WC_Tax::get_rates_for_tax_class( 'iva-normal-con-re' );
            $taxes = array();
            foreach ( $taxes_re as $tax_class ) { 
                $taxes[$tax_class->tax_rate_id] =  $price*floatval($tax_class->tax_rate)/100;
            }
            break;
        }  
    }     
   return $taxes;
  
 }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calc_shipping_tax', 'yourname_fix_shipping_tax',10,3);
```